# Single SQL query that updates multiple field value

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

i am troubling in following situation : 
i am getting some value.let suppose i am getting 1000.
And i have a table as follow.

[image]

now when i get value i need a single query that will update all this table.
As example i will run untill all amount will be paid or it taken value becomes zero.
if value is paid status becomes 1.

After updating table looks like this
[image]

If in last value will greater than zero. than store it on any of variable.

I Do This

```
$userval = 1000;
$sql = "
        update challan_1 t1,
        (
            SELECT x.id , SUM(y.bal) balance
            FROM (
                    SELECT *,amount - '$userval' bal FROM challan_1
                 ) x
            JOIN
                 (
                    SELECT *,paid - amount bal FROM challan_1
                 ) y
            ON
            y.id <= x.id GROUP BY x.id
        )t2 set t1.paid =balance WHERE t1.id = t2.id
      ";

echo $sql;
```

But it will Gives following result.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use this query and it update paid field as per requirement.

```
SELECT x.id , x.amount , x.amount as paid_amount , SUM(y.bal) as total, x.reciept_no
    FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT *,paid bal FROM challan_1 
    ) x 
    JOIN 
    ( 
        SELECT *,amount bal FROM challan_1 
    )y
    ON y.id <= x.id 
    GROUP BY x.id 
    HAVING total <= '500'
```